# Python writes chinese characters to text document

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to Python and I have been trying to tokenize a text file and write the results into another text file. However, when I print the results, I get what I want but while trying to write to a text file, it becomes gibberish.

Here is my code:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
with open ('F:\\Project\\nega.txt', 'r') as fin, open('tokens.txt', 'w') as out_file:
for line in fin:
    tokn = word_tokenize(line)
    for word in tokn:
        #print(word)
        out_file.write(word)
```

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is that the file is being in a different encoding that is expected by your editor.  See if the file is parsed properly when setting your editor to use UTF-8 or ANSI as opposed to the default.

Comment: Thanks @DerekBrown I used another editor and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

So summarize (for future viewers)- the issue is due to the encoding of the file. Most editors use the `UTF-8` encoding, though many Windows editors tend towards the `ANSI` standard.  There are thus two ways of addressing this issue:

1. Change the output encoding in Python:

```python
# UTF-8 
open(fname, "w", encoding="utf-8")

# ANSI
open(fname, "w", encoding="ansi")
```

2. Use a different editor (or an editor which allows you to select the encoding).